# How to add SearchBar in CollectionView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

Trying to add a header SearchBar CollectionView, but get an error:

> Illegal Configuration: Connection "searchBar" cannot have a prototype
>   object as its destination.

Comment: when u get this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: arrange your view like this]

arrange your view like this, and its related delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the "searchBar" above the collection view not upon the header of the collection view. Think if the collectionView has multiple sections, it will definitely cause a problem while scrolling the collectionView, hence you need to add the searchBar just above the collectionView not upon it's header.